# Use jQuery input mask for a ratios?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-inputmask

I'm using [this](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask) jquery input mask plugin to try and create an input field where the user can enter a ratio that adds up to 100%. E.g. `10% / 90%`

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="input" data-inputmask="'mask': '99/99', placeholder="50/50">
```

Both parts of the input must add up to 100. So if the user types `20`, then on the right, the number should be `80` e.g. `20/80`. If the number `80` is changed to `40`, then the number 20 on the left should automatically be changed to `60`. It shouldn't let you put in a number over 100.

This is my attempt so far but it's not working as expected. I'm unsure of how to create an `if()` statement around whether the user is editing the left side or the right. I only want the left value to change, if the right value is being edited and vice versa. 
Without this, my code will just replace the **both** sides of the ratio.

```
$('#input').keyup(function(){
    var user_ratio = $(this).val().split('/');
    var left = 100 - parseInt(user_ratio[1]); //65
    var right = 100 - parseInt(user_ratio[0]); //35
    var $(this).val(left+'/'+right);
});
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should store previous value somehow. Here just an idea that need to be developed. Also if designer is understanding person, I would probably use two inputs with "%" as a label for such purposes (it's mush simpler and more stable)

```js
$('#input').val('99%/99%') // for demo

function arrayFromValue(val) {
  return val.split('/').map(function(str) {return isNaN(parseInt(str)) ? 0 : parseInt(str)});
}

var $input = $('#input'), 
    currentValue = arrayFromValue( $input.val() );

$input.on('keyup', function() {
    var ratio = arrayFromValue( $(this).val() );
    
    // if the same value return
    if(currentValue[0] === ratio[0] && currentValue[1] === ratio[1]) return;
    
    // if more than 100 return with previous value
    if(ratio[0] > 100 || ratio[1] > 100) {
      return $(this).val(currentValue[0] + '%/' + currentValue[1] + '%');
    }
    
    var left = currentValue[1] !== ratio[1] ? 100 - ratio[1] : ratio[0];
    var right = currentValue[0] !== ratio[0] ? 100 - ratio[0] : ratio[1];

    currentValue = [left, right];
    $(this).val(left + '%/' + right + '%');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="input" type="text" />
```

Comment: Works great, thanks. The reason I wished to use one input was to slimline my form as there are many inputs that need to be ratio inputs.